# After leaving room, showing black screen in safari browser in RTCMultiConnection

Tags: webrtc, mobile-safari, rtcmulticonnection

I am using latest version of RTCMultiConnection and I am facing an issue in safari browser. Issue is after leaving , instead of removing screen, it is showing black screen. This issue is there in RTCMultiConnection demos also. Also I have an another issue. If 3rd user is connected then another user's screen is paused in safari browser. Please give me solution to resolve an issue.

Thanks in advance...